# OS X equivalent of Windows keyboard commands to access in-application menus?

Tags: macos, keyboard, switching

In Windows, I often use the keyboard commands to navigate through the menus in a program.  For example, in Photoshop, I can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to quickly **Save for Web & Devices**.  Or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to **Clear Guides**.  This is great when there is no keyboard command for a menu item that I want to use, or the existing keyboard command requires too many fingers.

How can I translate this functionality to OS X (OS X 10.5.8 in case it matters)?  How can I navigation through an applications's menus using keyboard commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, which moves the focus to the  symbol in the menu bar. Then use the arrow keys to move around, or just type the start of a menu name to highlight it. With a menu name highlighted, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to expand it. In an open menu, you can type the start of a menu item to highlight it. Once highlighted, press <kbd>Space</kbd> again to “click” it.

So, to get to “Save for Web & Devices” in Photoshop, you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> until you focus “Save for Web & Devices”, then <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Of course, the built-in keyboard shortcut for that option is much easier to type: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Using the Mac's keyboard shortcut got a lot easier for me when I figured out what ⌥ was.  (On my MBA, it's labeled "option" on the key.)

Comment: @KatieK I can imagine! When in doubt, you can always refer to http://mackeys.info/ ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could also assign shortcuts to AppleScripts like this with an app like Alfred or FastScripts:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    click menu bar 1's menu bar item 3 -- usually File
end tell
```

They won't work in full screen though. And it's not that much faster than just using a mouse really.

You can also trigger menu items by searching after focusing the help menu with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.

Comment: Plus one for the command-? variant (: